# How to get $\frac{d}{dt}(D_yx(t,y))=[D_xf(t,x(t,y))](D_yx(t,y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the nonlinear DE $x'=f(t,x)$ where $f\in C^1$. For a fixed $\tau$ let $x(t,y)$ be the solution of the IVP
$$
x'=f(t,x), x(\tau)=y
$$

How to get the equation of variation for the $n\times n$ Jacobian matrix $D_yx$ is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(D_yx(t,y))=[D_xf(t,x(t,y))](D_yx(t,y))
$$

And thus
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(det(D_yx(t,y)))=tr([D_xf(t,x(t,y))])det((D_yx(t,y)))
$$

---

I am confused about the derivative. If we take derivative of $D_y x$ w.r.t. $t$, why we have $D_x f$? Is that we exchange the derivative?
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(D_yx(t,y))=D_y[\frac{d}{dt}(x(t,y))]=?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to the exchange of order of the derivatives, with the understanding that when changing the simple solution to some kind of flow, $\frac{d}{dt}$ also has to become a partial derivative, and should better be written as $D_t$ or $\partial_t$.

Now $x$ is the solution of the differential equation $\dot x=f(t,x)$, and $y$ is some parameter, here the initial condition (it could also be a parameter in the ODE, the calculus would not change much). The next step is just to replace $D_tx(t;y)$ with $f(t,x(t;y))$.

So we are at $D_y [f(t,x(t;y))]$. Now apply the chain rule
$$
D_y [f(t,x(t;y))] = [(D_x f)(t,x(t;y))]\,D_yf(t;y).
$$
Note that the index variable in the derivative only indicates the place in the function arguments that the derivative is taken for. It does not refer to what actually is inside these arguments, their values or composition. If that is ambiguous, freely apply parentheses, brackets etc.